# How does WCF DataContractJsonSerializer deserialize a json DateTime?

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have 2 datetime json strings, the only difference is the offset part, one is -08, the other one is -09:

```
"/Date(946713600000-0800)/"
"/Date(946713600000-0900)/"
```

When I deserialize them using DataContractJsonSerializer

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DateTime));

byte[] byteArray1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\"\\/Date(946713600000-0800)\\/\"");
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(byteArray1);
var datetime1 = serializer.ReadObject(stream1 );

byte[] byteArray2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\"\\/Date(946713600000-0900)\\/\"");
MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream(byteArray2);
var datetime2 = serializer.ReadObject(stream2 );
```

The result supersize me, datetime1 and datetime2  are exactly the same!
both are {1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM},  datetime1.Kind and datetime2.Kind are both Local.

I expect they have one hour difference. Why they are same?

Answer (score 1):

The time portion is the same value between the two dates. The offset, represented as -0900 and -0800, in your example, is just extra information that denotes the offset from UTC that the local time was captured in.

Comment: -0800 and -0900 mean the 2 datetime were created in a different time zone. the time portion 946713600000 represents the offset from 1970:01-01 00:00:00 in UTC, it is {1/1/2000 8:00:00 AM} in UTC. When you parse them into a certain time zone, they should be different, because their UTC are the same. I feel your answer doesn't explain why datetime1 and datetime2 are the same.

Comment: Those dates are a bit different than the "Z"ulu dates that come across the wire in pox and soap serialization and in some specially crafted json formats. I don't think the json/javascript standard has been formalized to the point that you are expecting or perhaps the serializer does not follow the standard or is lacking what you are advocating.